# Codeigniter: how to access controllers in ‘admin’ directory

Tags: codeigniter

I have created an `admin` folder in `controllers` folder. I have created a controller `user` in `controllers/admin` folder.

The following line was added to routes.php:

```
$route[‘admin/(:any)’] = ‘admin/([a-zA-Z0-9/_]+)’;
```

The following url is used to access the `user` controller in `controllers/admin` folder.

```
http://localhost/main/forum/admin/user/
```

My application is routed to default controller and my urls are containing variable like as follows:

```
http://localhost/main/forum/admin/user/view
http://localhost/main/forum/admin/user/create
http://localhost/main/forum/admin/user/delete/uid/1/uname/my_name
http://localhost/main/forum/admin/dashboard/first_var/2/second_var/3/third_var/4
```

Thanks in advance.

*Also posted on the CodeIgniter forums: [Code Igniter forum link](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/181593/)*

Comment: You need to migrate the question information from the forum site to here if you want responses.

Comment: Where is the base of your CodeIgniter installation located? They key you've added to your `$route` array may need to be more specific.

Comment: So I have to add more than one routers to handle a single directory 'admin' for this purpose ? My basepath is 'http://localhost/main/forum/'

Comment: @ Jared. There's not much info on the forum either.

Comment: jerad ...can you explain a little bit what type of info you require. Iam always here to send you the required info. Thanks

Comment: @user625870. "where is the base of your codeigniter installation?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're installation is in the forum directory, then what you are doing is right. In fact, you don't need routes.

Simply going to `your_app_installation/admin/user` would point to `your_app_installation/admin/user`.